# Stack overflow with tail recursion

Tags: java, tail-recursion

Why am I getting a stack overflow exception? Isn't this meant to be a tail recursive function?

```
public static int tailFact(int n, int mult) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return mult;
    }else {
        return tailFact(n-1, n*mult);
    }
}

public static int factT(int n) {
    return tailFact(n, 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {            
            factT(100000);
}


/*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

  at test3.Test.tailFact(Test.java:13)
  at test3.Test.tailFact(Test.java:13)
  ...
*/
```

Comment: Where did it say that java supports tail recursion? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/272061/why-doesnt-java-have-optimization-for-tail-recursion-at-all or http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/tail-call-optimization-and-java/240167044

Comment: Never knew it didn't - I'm fairly new, but thanks for the kind answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't support tail recursion.